# Why does ftp not work with concatenated strings?

Tags: vba, ftp, string-concatenation

I have been scratching my head for hours on this one. I have a VBA macro that generates a text file containing a list of ftp commands that I will use with "ftp -s:". So far so good. However ftp does something very weird and ***splits*** a concatenated string an place it at the beginning of the line. I will give an example to better illustrate this. The following is the structure of the text file:

myUserName

myPassword

get myFile.**zip**

close

The characters in bold indicate where the concatenation occurred using `Print #1, "get " & fileName & ".zip"`

So when I run `ftp -s:Commands.txt myftp.me.com` i am able to login fine, except when ftp gets to third line with the get command. The ".zip" is split and placed in the beginning of the command line and basically executes `.zip get myFile`

I do not see this when I manually type the commands into a text file.

Any ideas on what might be happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you opened VBA generated file Commands.txt in a text editer, the line "get myFile.zip" is OK?

Comment: Yes, the line "get myFile.zip" looks just fine. This is really weird

Answer (score 0):

I do not know, why this should not work, but what you may try, is to add quotes " " around the file names. normally this should work without quotes if you have no spaces in the filename, but I would give it a try.

`Print #1, "get """ & fileName & ".zip"""`